# How to dedicate hostgroup to user in Nagios

Tags: nagios

I'm trying to set up new user who just watch a hostgroup:

I made that user like this:

```
define contact{
    contact_name                    somedude
    alias                           somedude
    service_notification_period     24x7
    host_notification_period        24x7
    service_notification_options    w,u,c,r
    host_notification_options       d,r
    service_notification_commands   notify-service-by-email
    host_notification_commands      notify-host-by-email
    email                           somedude@example.org
}


define contactgroup {
    contactgroup_name       somegroup
    members                 somedude
}

define host {
    host_name       someserver.example.org
    contact_groups  somegroup
    address         1.2.3.4
    use             generic-host
    hostgroups      somehostgroup
    notifications_enabled           1
}


define hostgroup {
                hostgroup_name somehostgroup
                alias          somealias

        }

htpasswd /etc/nagios3/htpasswd.users somedude
```

And I can see the host in the option contact_groups ,but i can`t see host in the option hostgroup. I receive the error told me, i dont allow to see that (hostgroup)

Error:

> It appears as though you do not have permission to view information
>   for any of the hosts you requested... If you believe this is an error,
>   check the HTTP server authentication requirements for accessing this
>   CGI and check the authorization options in your CGI configuration
>   file.

How i configure that to see hostgroup?

Best regards

Comment: Does the hostgroup exist? I don't see it in your config.

Comment: Sorry i forgot add that line, now i edit and put   @Catherine Maclnnes

Comment: I tried with add one new template with contact_groups and hostgroups and put in the host, but the error is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To view a hostgroup, the user must be have permission to view (e.g., be a contact) for every host in the hostgroup.

Comment: But, i dont know how to implement that solution, i can`t add contact to hostgroup @keith   thank for your help

Comment: Sorry, i understand now, I implement the contact_groups in every host of the hostgroup and works fine. thank you @keith